# How can i make my web scraper to stop on the last page without hard coding the last page value (python)?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping from a website with pages from 1 to 40. This is the website. https://gb.kompass.com/d/surrey/gb_gbr09_sw/
as you can see the pagination doesn't have a next button so i need to pass in the page number in my api call. I have added a range from 1 to 41 because I manually check there are 41 pages. I don't want to hard code the last page number. What can I do to make my code more scalable so that it will stop on the last page?

Please note when it reaches the last page the website automatically go back to the first page from the website.

```
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"
}

def get_links():
    try:
        driver = uc.Chrome()
        driver.get(
            'https://url')
        time.sleep(15)
        print("driver", driver)
        content = driver.page_source

        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
        body = soup.body
        LINKS = []
        for x in range(1, 41):
            tags = body.find_all('div', {'class': 'col col-left company-container'})
            for tag in tags:
                try:
                    a = tag.find_all('a', href=True)
                    print("a", a[0].get('href'))
                    url = a[0].get('href')
                    LINKS.append(url)
                    df = pd.DataFrame({
                        'LINKS': LINKS
                    })
                    df.to_csv('Links.csv', index=False)
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    next_page = 'https://url/page-' + str(x) + '/'
                    print('next_page', next_page)
                    driver.get(next_page)
                    time.sleep(5)
                    content = driver.page_source
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
                    body = soup.body
                 except:
                    pass

    except:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links()
```

Comment: can you provide the url?

Comment: I don't know why I can't run to the last page. When I click to the last page, it will show `No result found`.

Comment: I think you should use a while loop, you can record the first data on the first page, and every time you enter the next page, check whether the first data on the first page is the same as the current one.

Comment: Never post a shortened url: whoever is willing to invest time and effort to help you for free should trust the link he's clicking on.

Comment: https://gb.kompass.com/d/surrey/gb_gbr09_sw/

Comment: run in `while`-loop and find some element which exist (or not exist) only on last page. For example last page may not have button `>` with link to next page. And last page has class `active` on last element in pagination.

Comment: don't use `except: pass` - because you may have some important error and you will not now it. And later you will ask question: `"why it doesn't work if I don't get any error"`. You could at least do `except Exception as ex: print("Exception:", ex)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in `while`-loop and check some element which exists (or not exists) only on last page.

Usually `pagination` is useful for this.

For example this last page doesn't have button `>` with link to next page.
And last page has class `active` on last element in pagination. And I use this to detect last page

In this code I use `number = 38` only to fast test it but you should start with `number = 1`

```
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"
}

def get_links():
    
    # --- before loop ---
    
    LINKS = []
    
    # --- loop ---
    
    try:
        driver = uc.Chrome()
        url = 'https://gb.kompass.com/d/surrey/gb_gbr09_sw/'
        
        number = 38
        #number = 1
        while True:
            print(f'page {number}:', url)
            
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(5)
            html = driver.page_source
        
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

            # -----
            
            tags = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col col-left company-container'})
            for tag in tags:
                a = tag.find_all('a', href=True)
                url = a[0].get('href')
                print("url:", url)
                LINKS.append(url)

            # -----

            pagination = soup.select('ul.pagination li')
            last = pagination[-1]
            
            if 'active' in last.attrs.get('class'):
                print('it is last page')
                break
            else:
                number += 1
                url = f'https://gb.kompass.com/d/surrey/gb_gbr09_sw/page-{number}/'

    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:', ex)

    # --- after loop ---
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'LINKS': LINKS})
    df.to_csv('Links.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links()
```